# Continue forEach from inside a callback function?

Tags: javascript

I have a loop like this:

```
attributes.forEach((attribute) => {
    if(Boolean( q[attribute] )){
        test = req.assert(attribute, 'required').optional().notEmpty();
        isValid(test, callback)
        req.user.setAttribute(attribute, q[attribute]);
    }
});
```

callback is  callback-function that gets triggered if the test is invalid. I wish to do a return to get to the next itteration, but if I do

```
isValid(test, function(){
    return;
})
```

It will only return the callback  from the callback function.

Comment: Can we see the definition of the isValid function?

Comment: something like this: if(isValid(test, callback)){return;} while returning true/false from isvalid function

Answer (score 1):

Check the return value of isValid. If it is true, then `return`. Here is a simplified example since I do not see your entire dataset:

```js
function isThree(num) {
  return (num == 3);
}


[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].forEach(num => {
  if (isThree(num)) {
    return
  }
  console.log(num);
})
```

Notice that "3" was not logged to the console.